# How to get "AM/PM" in data read from a form input (type=time)?

Tags: php, html, html-input

I have this code:

```
<input class="meting" name="meetingtime" value="<?php echo $_POST['meetingtime'] ?>" type="time"/>

<?php
    $time = $_POST['meetingtime'];
    echo $time; // the output of this is only the numbers
?>
```

How can I get the AM/PM values in PHP?

Comment: chrome is a web browser, and has nothing to do with running PHP code

Comment: Where do you set `$time`?

Comment: The output of `echo $time` should be the value that the user has entered in the `meetingtime` field of the form, so what are you entering in the `meetingtime` field?

Comment: This [link](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) might help you.

Comment: If one of the answers below contains the correct answer to your question, please mark it as Accepted. It's a green checkbox just underneath the Vote Up/Down buttons to the left of each answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Oct 2022

PHP has a build in function to do that.

```
$time = $_POST['meetingtime'];
echo date("g:i a", $time);
// 10:22 AM
```

### Fatal error?

If you get a fatal error try adding `strtotime()` to the time.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: date(): Argument #2 ($timestamp) must be of type ?int...
```

```
$time = $_POST['meetingtime'];
echo date("g:i a", strtotime($time));
// 10:22 AM
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 inputs such as `date`, `time`, and `datetime` will display to the user in a locale-aware format. For instance, in America a date field would probably be formatted as MM/DD/YYYY (because this somehow makes sense to them...) but in Europe it would be DD/MM/YYYY. However, in both cases the server would receive YYYY-MM-DD (the standard date format)

A similar thing applies to time. If your computer is set to 24-hour clocks, then it will not use AM/PM, whereas a 12-hour setting will. Either way, it sends a 24-hour time because that is the standard.

Comment: yea, when i enter 12:30 AM it turns 00:30, maybe the computer is not set into 12hr format. how can we set the time format into 12hr anyway?

Answer (score 2):

What I see (in the USA)...

If the input time is: `9:45 PM`, then the value of `$_POST['meetingtime']` is `23:45`.

To get AM/PM, you need to check if the value is anything less than 12:00 is AM or greater or equal to 12:00 is PM.

An easy way to do this is to get the hour value by using `intval()`:

```
echo intval($time) < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
```

Answer (score 1):

if

> the output of this is only the numbers

then it's probably a timestamp, and you'll have for example to use date() to turn it into readable date format.

Example giving March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm :
(assuming $time is a timestamp long number)

```
<?php echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $time); ?>
```